# Java Recursion Example

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on a problem for a class where a user input a number and if it is 1000 or greater you have to add commas. So if the user put 12300, the output would be 12,300. I was able to figure out how to do it for numbers below 1 million, but when I input a number like 1234567 it doesn't print anything at all. Here is the code for the method:

```
public static String commas(long l) {
    String s = "";
    String pt1;
    String pt2;
    long pt1Number;
    long pt2Number;

    if (l < 1) {
            return String.valueOf(l);

    } else {

        pt1Number = l / 1000;
        pt2Number = l % 1000;

        if (pt1Number < 1000) {
            pt1 = String.valueOf(pt1Number);
            pt2 = String.valueOf(pt2Number);
            s = pt1 + "," + pt2;

        } else {
            commas(pt1Number);

        }

    }

    return s;

}

}
```

Does anyone see what might be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you meant this?

```
public static String commas(long input) {
        if (input < 1000) {
            return String.valueOf(input);
        } else {
            long pt1Number = input / 1000;
            long pt2Number = input % 1000;
            return commas(pt1Number) + ","
                   + (pt2Number==0l?"000":String.valueOf(pt2Number));
            }

    }
```

some problems in your codes:

- incorrect usage of recursion, you have realized that
- didn't check the case, if `%1000==0`, you should concat `000`, E.g. `input=2000`
- avoid to use `l` as parameter name for better readability , looks similar as  `1`

Comment: yes, thanks for your help. But what exactly does "pt2Number==0l?"000":" do? I haven't learned that yet

Comment: @BenjaminPorter `c=condition?a:b` `=>` `if condition true, c=a, else c=b`

Answer (score 0):

In your `else` (when `pt1Number` is >= 1000), you're doing nothing with the result of `commas(pt1Number)`. You call the function, and totally ignore its result. Afterwards, you return `s`, which is still empty.

Maybe you meant...

```java
else {
  s = commas(pt1Number);
}
```

...instead of:

```java
else {
  commas(pt1Number);
}
```

Comment: my parameter is a long but im returning a string(it has to be that way for the assignment) so I dont think your suggestion would work...

Comment: My suggestion was to do _something_ with the result of `commas(pt1Number);`. For example, store it in `s`. The input parameter is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your Program is not working for at-least minor cases
i.e.
for 11 output is 0,11
for 1000 output is 1,0

please change your logic accordingly..

@Kent 1010 for this your Output is 1,10

as per me your code should be modified like below

```
public class Comma {
public static String commas(long l) {
    String s = "";
    long pt1Number;long pt2Number;
    if (l < 1000) {
            return String.valueOf(l);
    } else {
        pt1Number = l / 1000;
        pt2Number = l % 1000;
        if (pt1Number < 1000) {
            if (pt2Number == 0) {
                s=pt1Number+","+"000";
            }else if(pt2Number>0 &&pt2Number<10)
            {
                s=pt1Number+","+"00"+pt2Number;
            }
            else if(pt2Number>9 &&pt2Number<100)
            {
                s=pt1Number+","+"0"+pt2Number;
            }
        } else {

            if (pt2Number == 0) {
                s=commas(pt1Number)+","+"000";
            }else if(pt2Number>0 &&pt2Number<10)
            {
                s=commas(pt1Number)+","+"00"+pt2Number;
            }
            else if(pt2Number>9 &&pt2Number<100)
            {
                s=commas(pt1Number)+","+"0"+pt2Number;
            }

        }
        return s;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(commas(1000009));
}
```

}